# jquery code refactoring tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, refactoring

Is there any tools that helps refactoring my javascript(jquery) code? For small snippet it doesn't matter but while developing new jquery plugin there will be lines of code where refactoring is required for sure.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

I come across [this](http://www.slideshare.net/fgalassi/refactoring-to-unobtrusive-javascript) while searching about refactoring. However, perhaps this will not solve your issue. But, I think you can find any clue.

Also, I cannot find any plugin. You can tag if you found it.

Thanking you.

Comment: Link explain about how to avoid : 1. js code inside html, 2. css code inside js and so on.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ has a powerful refactoring capabilities.